# data platform monitoring tools options

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, elastic-stack, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

We have aws based data pipelines having different components like kinesis lambda firehose s3 dynamodb and emr for spark jobs.
We need to implement monitoring system across all these components mostly monitoring the processing time taken at each point and if any bottlenecks.

Can anybody please guide if they have implemented such monitoring system. I am more interested in building the prometheus and grafana based system

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Cloudwatch exporter to take the metrics to a Prometheus server.

There are 2 main Cloudwatch exporters:

- [Cloudwatch exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter): The 'official' one, written in Java. The main handicap is that it does not implement GetMetricsData API call, so it can provoke API throttling if there are many resources in the namespace.
- [Yet another Cloudwatch Exporter](https://github.com/ivx/yet-another-cloudwatch-exporter): This one is written in go and implements GetMetricsData, which allows to make up to 500 metrics requests in a single API call.

In both the configuration is similar and in the repositories there are configuration files available as examples.

AWS has a doc about the convenience of [using GetMetricsData instead of GetMetricStatistics](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-getmetricdata-api/).

Answer (score 0):

For your AWS services you can use [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) and [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) for monitoring. For Apache Spark you can also use the [Spark Web UI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-ui.html).

Comment: can you elaborate more on cloudwatch configuration which can show time taken by api calls to dnamodb, time taken to process kinesis stream.

Comment: I would suggest you check out the AWS documentation on this. For API calls you can use AWS CloudTrail. I edited my answer.